# Can making a curl request to hundreds of sites be considered an attack by some hosts?

Tags: php, curl, server, hosting, web-hosting

Sometimes we don't have the APIs we would like to, and this is one of these cases.

I want to extract certain information from certain website, so I was considering using a CURL request to hundreds of pages within a site in a programmatically way by using a CRON job in my server.

Then caching the response and firing it again after one or multiple days.

Could that potentially be considered as some kind of attack by the server who might see hundreds of calls to certain sites in a very short period of time from the same server IP?

Lets say, 500 hundred curls?

What would you recommend me? Perhaps making use of the `sleep` command from curl to curl to reduce the frequency of those requests?

Comment: `500 hundred curls` as in 50,000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely do this. However you should keep a few things in mind:

1. Most competent sites will have a clause in their Terms of Service which prohibit the use of the site in anyway other than the interface provided.
2. If the site see's what you are doing and notices a detrimental effect on their network they will block your ip (our organization was running into this issue enough that it warranted us developing a program that logs ips and the rate at which they access content, then if they attempt to access more than x number of pages in y number of seconds we ban the ip for z minutes), however you might be able to circumvent this by utilizing the `sleep` command as you had mentioned.
3. If you require information on the page that is loaded dynamically via javascript after the markup has been rendered, the response you receive from your curl request will not include this information. For cases such as these there are programs such as [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) which allow you to write scripts in your browser to carry out actions programmatically as if you were actually using the browser.

As mentioned by @RyanCady the best solution may be to reach out to the owner of the site and explain what you are doing and see if they can accommodate your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of situations where your scripts could end up getting blocked by the website's firewall. One of the best steps you can take in seeing if this is allowed is by contacting the site owner and letting them know what you want to do. If that's not possible read their Terms of Service, and see if it's strictly prohibited.

If time is not of the essence when making these calls then, yes, you can definitely utilize the `sleep` command to delay the time between each request, and I would recommend it if you find out you need to make a few less requests per second.